# How add mono to my PATH?

Tags: environment-variables, mono, monodevelop, configure

I want to install monodevelop-4.2.1 from source under Ubuntu 12.4.3 but when I execute :

> ./configure --prefix=`pkg-config --variable=prefix mono`

it shows me that :

> configure: error: Can't find "mono" in your PATH

how could I add it to my PATH ?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to do that, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo nano ~/.profile
```

And add the following line:

```
export PATH=path_of_mono:$PATH
```

Replace path_of_mono with the correct path of mono.

Comment: Ty Mitch , what is the path_of_mono ? you mean my source folder ? I added it and nothing happened .

Comment: Path where mono resides.  You may look in `/usr/share/applications/`, `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, or `/usr/local/bin`.